# Prove the equality into a matrix norm and two vectors norm since the matrix is the multiplication of one vector and the transpose of the other one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

We have that $M=xy^t$, where $x,y \in \Re^n$ and they are non void. How can I prove the following equality? $$ ||M||_2=||x||_2||y||_2 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of the $2$-norm for real matrices we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|M\|_2 &= \mathrm{Tr}[M^T M]^{1/2} \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[(xy^T)^Txy^T]^{1/2} \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[yx^T xy^T]^{1/2} \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[y(x^T x) y^T]^{1/2} \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[y (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2) y^T]^{1/2} \\
&= (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^{1/2}\mathrm{Tr}[y y^T]^{1/2} \\
&= (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^{1/2} \\
&= \|x\|_2 \|y\|_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
You may want to verify some of the steps in more detail if they are not clear.